# Named pipes over network

Tags: windows, delphi-7, named-pipes

I wrote a very simple code to set up a "server" that creates a named pipe and waits for a client to connect. As soon as the client opens the pipe, the server sends its data (a block of about 10mb) and the client is supposed to read it and close the connection.

The real catch now is: When the pipe is working with local names (\.\pipe\xxx) it does send all the data without any problem but if i change the path to a network name (\computer\pipe\xxx) it changes behavior and client can only read about 65000~ bytes, but it does not complete read operation even when i loop it (i suppose it breaks in 65k blocks to send over network since i'm using a network name, it happens even locally). ReadFile reads the 65k block and returns TRUE, if i try to force ReadFile again in the pipe it reads 0 bytes.

The flags i'm using to create the pipe are PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, PIPE_WAIT, PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS

Here is a piece of what the code should look like (the code is somewhere else and i can't access it right now but as i said before, it is as simple as it gets)

```
lPipe := CreateFileA('\\.\pipe\test', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
ReadFile(lPipe, lMemoryStream.Memory^, 1024*1024*15, lBytesRead, nil);
CloseHandle(lPipe);
```

Comment: If you expect help with your code you need to include the code in your question. Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31395015/edit) to show your reading code.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid code because it would narrow the answers i guess. I am currently using delphi 7 and the code is really straightforward, as simple as CreateFile->ReadFile->CloseHandle but i will add it to the post to give a better picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation for WriteFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Pipe write operations across a network are limited to 65,535 bytes per write. For more information regarding pipes, see the Remarks section.

To get past this, you'll have to set up the server to send the data in chunks.